# Google Analytics pageviews tracking were not working

Tags: google-analytics

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){
i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;
i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();
a=s.createElement(o),      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
a.async=1;
a.src=g;
m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)       })
(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'Tracking ID', 'Domain');  // Replace with your property ID.

ga('send', 'pageview','URL');
```

Comment: Could you please explain your question in a better manner? perhaps add some text

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is this line:

```
ga('create', 'Tracking ID', 'Domain');  // Replace with your property ID.
```

It should have your GA property Id in it which will begin with UA. Something like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'auto');  // Replace with your property ID.
```

You can find the property id under the Home section of Google Analytics. Or alternatively look at Admin->Property->Tracking Info-Tracking Code.